# Is there a way for Rust macros to act as text substitutions like in C?

Tags: macros, rust, preprocessor

In C, if you wanted to, you could:

```
#define    do     {
#define    end    }

// ...

if (foo == bar) do
    foo += 5;
    bar /= foo;
end
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Rust?

Answer (score 9):

No (thankfully). Rust macros must always expand to a complete AST node.

If you *need* textual substitution, use a tool suited for that job such as `sed`, `awk`, `m4`, the C preprocessor, etc. That can likely be driven by a build script.

Comment: I don't NEED it per se, it's just that brackets are horrible to my eyes coming from quite some time working in languages that renounced for the most part such concepts like python, haskell, f#, matlab, etc. and was looking for a way to make the syntax prettier.

Comment: @RaresDima speaking plainly, I think that's just something you need to get over to be a professional programmer. Different languages have different syntaxes, idioms, naming conventions, indenting styles, etc. *When in Rome, do as the Romans do*. If you replace curlies with keywords or if you make it whitespace-sensitive, you **aren't writing Rust anymore**. You then have to translate every example you ever see to your dialect, translate back when asking for help, you get no help from your editors or tooling. At that point, you might as well just write your own language.

Comment: @RaresDima Furthermore, doing so with simple text substitution is not a good way to go.

Answer (score 4):

There is a toy project that does this, in fact: [slag](https://github.com/mystor/slag). I have never tried it, though.

It comes with this helpful advice:

> #### Should I use this?
>
> No. Use the default rust syntax.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "Is there a way for Rust macros to act as text substitutions like in C?" It also doesn't answer the implied question of "can I use do/end blocks instead of curly braces?" as slag is whitespace sensitive, instead. This would be better off as a comment.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, fair point. I suppose I was posting to answer the follow-up comment rather than the original question.